# How should we disambiguate the [apn] tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms, retag-request

The current tag wiki excerpt for [apn](/questions/tagged/apn) (47 questions) states:

> Apple Push Notification allows developers to push near real-time information to iOS devices

However, that doesn't seem to agree with the related tags:

[image: screenshot showing tag:android as the most related tag]

---

Apparently "APN" is sometimes used as an acronym for "[Access Point Name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_Point_Name)", in which case it isn't specific to iOS development. So the tag, as it is currently used, doesn't seem to have a clear meaning.

It seems that [apn](/questions/tagged/apn) is synonymous to [apple-push-notification](/questions/tagged/apple-push-notification) (346 questions) when the former is used for iOS-related questions. The wiki excerpt for [apple-push-notification](/questions/tagged/apple-push-notification) is also much more detailed:

> The Apple Push Notification Service is a service created by Apple Inc.
> that was launched together with iOS 3.0.APNS is used together with Mac
> OS X Lion Server to push update notifications to clients that have
> registered to receive updates via a configuration profile and are also
> using the server's mail, calendar and contacts services. This means
> that devices such as the iPhone and applications like iCal on the Mac
> can receive a notification

There is also [apns](/questions/tagged/apns) (300 questions) which has an excerpt of median length and a wiki of superior length. It is almost definitely synonymous to [apple-push-notification](/questions/tagged/apple-push-notification) (or vice-versa). Its wiki excerpt:

> Apple Push Notification Service (APNs for short) is the centerpiece of
> the push notifications feature. It is a robust and highly efficient
> service for propagating information to devices (such as iPhone, iPad,
> and iPod touch devices) and computers (such as Macintosh computers
> running MacOS 10.7).

---

#### Possible solution

To clean up this mess, I suggest we take (each of) the following steps:

- change [apn](/questions/tagged/apn)'s wiki to reflect only its use as "Access Point Name"
- retag the iOS-specific posts tagged with [apn](/questions/tagged/apn) to [apple-push-notifications](/questions/tagged/apple-push-notifications) or [apns](/questions/tagged/apns)
- synonymize [apns](/questions/tagged/apns) and [apple-push-notifications](/questions/tagged/apple-push-notifications) (not sure which should map to which, but I would keep the wiki from [apns](/questions/tagged/apns)).

Should we do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would propose using [access-point-name](/questions/tagged/access-point-name) and [apple-push-notifications](/questions/tagged/apple-push-notifications) as the major tags.  [apn](/questions/tagged/apn) and [apns](/questions/tagged/apns) shouldn't be split across the two, given that the latter is just the plural of the former.  I would make them both synonyms for [access-point-name](/questions/tagged/access-point-name).

Comment: I like this for the sake of clarity, but I think it could lead to an initial slew of iOS-related posts mistakenly tagged [apns] (and consequently synonymized to [access-point-name]).

Comment: @JasonPlank I'm more of the mindset to fix the broken things instead of accomodate them, but your point is valid.

Comment: I'm sorry to disagree with you but APNs is the good way to call the Apple Push Notification Service. (cf my answer).

Answer (score 1):

I think `APN` and `Apple Push Notification` are wrong names. For notifications the official name is `Apple Push Notification Service` and every "good" iOS developer call it `APNs`. It has nothing to do with any plural form.

For me `apn` for the first case should go `access-point-name` and for the notifications it should go under the `apns` tag.

**So, answer is :**

As `apn` tag has only 52 questions it seems that is an unusual tag. We really should rename it to `access-point-name`.

`APNs` tag has more than 1K questions and other tags rely on it : `apns-php` `apns-csharp` etc. we can keep it as a shortcut.

Sources :
[Apple Push Notification Service (Official Apple Documentation)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

[Apple Push Notification Service (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Push_Notification_Service)

Comment: Looking at the questions tagged `apns` now I agree that this is how the tags seem to be used.  Gotta love it when nothing had been done after 2 years :P

Comment: I'm not an expert about meta or Stackoverflow so I'm not sure what to do. But I'll try to clean a little bit ;)

Comment: Should you remove your answer ?