# We don't need three tags for Apple Push Notifications

Tags: discussion, tags

This was brought up [a few months ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112118/135887), but the cleanup that was performed then has deteriorated.

There are three -- count'em, *three* -- tags for Apple Push Notifications:

1. [apple-push-notifications](/questions/tagged/apple-push-notifications), 430 questions
2. [apns](/questions/tagged/apns), 346 questions
3. [apn](/questions/tagged/apn), 58 questions

From the previous question, [apn](/questions/tagged/apn) can also be an Android term.  The previous question suggested using [access-point-name](/questions/tagged/access-point-name), but there are no questions with that tag right now.

Sigh.

[apns](/questions/tagged/apns) should either be merged into [apple-push-notifications](/questions/tagged/apple-push-notifications) or become a synonym of it, with the more verbose tag being the master.

[apn](/questions/tagged/apn) is a bit sticker.  Should it simply go away and then try to rely on the New Tag Deletionist Cabal to keep it away?  Or should it become a synonym of [apple-push-notifications](/questions/tagged/apple-push-notifications), relying on Android users to notice [access-point-name](/questions/tagged/access-point-name)?

Comment: I have never, ever heard of "apn" being used to refer to Apple Push Notifications. I've only seen [apns]. Also, access point names aren't an Android thing.

Comment: The tag wiki and common use disagree.  Wait, why am I defending a tag wiki?  People never pay attention to them when tagging their questions...

Comment: [apns] = [a] [p]ain [n] a[s]s

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [apns](/questions/tagged/apns), my suggestion would be to make that a synonym for the more descriptive [apple-push-notifications](/questions/tagged/apple-push-notifications). If there's a possible alternate use for [apn](/questions/tagged/apn), given the lower number of questions there, I'd just retag things. Also, you could leave a note in the tag wiki summary for [apn] directing people to use [apple-push-notifications] if they are referring to Apple's technology.

For example, there's the [automatic-ref-counting](/questions/tagged/automatic-ref-counting) tag, an Apple technology that many abbreviate to ARC, but [arc](/questions/tagged/arc) can mean other things. Therefore, I edited the [arc] tag wiki summary to note that it was not to be used for automatic reference counting questions, and pointed people to [automatic-ref-counting]. That has significantly reduced the use of the [arc] tag, and I just retag the remaining questions that slip through. That seems to work reasonably well.

Unfortunately, I don't have enough upvotes in the [apple-push-notifications] tag to even suggest [apns] as a synonym, and getting others to vote on it might be tricky. This could be a job for the moderators.

Answer (score 2):

As nobody is using [access-point-name](/questions/tagged/access-point-name) I think we should not force users to use it, let them use [apn](/questions/tagged/apn) instead, as they are currently using. The reason is "Apple Push Notifications" is not abbreviated as "apn", but "Access Point Name" is.

Comment: Given that [tag:apn] currently says it's for Apple Push Notifications, and also given that nobody reads tag wikis when creating their questions, how do you propose to dissuade people from using [tag:apn] when they mean Apple Push Notifications?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the discussion here and in the question linked by the OP, I did the following :

1. changed tags of all Apple Push Notifications question that used [apn](/questions/tagged/apn) to [apple-push-notifications](/questions/tagged/apple-push-notifications).
2. Suggested [apns](/questions/tagged/apns) as a synonym to [apple-push-notifications](/questions/tagged/apple-push-notifications) (needs votes to be approved).
3. Edited the [apn](/questions/tagged/apn) tag wiki (my edit is pending approval).

Now there are 40 questions tagged [apn](/questions/tagged/apn), all of them about `Access Point Name`.