# relax tag synonym voting rules

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we allow 7.5K users  to suggest tag synonyms without a score of 5 in the tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103211/can-we-allow-7-5k-users-to-suggest-tag-synonyms-without-a-score-of-5-in-the-tag)

Is there any support for relaxing the [tag synonym voting rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92260/how-to-vote-for-tag-synonym)?

A [user proposed adding two tags to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/214386), [apple-push-notifications](/questions/tagged/apple-push-notifications) and [apns](/questions/tagged/apns). The [apple-push-notifications synonyms page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/apple-push-notifications/synonyms) says [apn](/questions/tagged/apn) is already suggested as a synonym, and I wanted to add `apns` and up-vote `apn`. (They seem like fairly obvious abbreviations and I know of no alternative meanings for either.)

But I don't have the reputation in the tag `apple-push-notifications`, so I can't participate at all. I'm used to being able to take steps towards fixing problems on the site and it feels awkward to be shunned in this instance.

Is this a problem? Have I missed some discussions in the past about opening up tag voting to 3k, 5k, 10k, or 20k users regardless of per-tag reputation? Or, perhaps send tag synonym requests from people without privileges through the suggested edits queue to make new suggestions eligible for voting? Or, perhaps allow half-votes for those of us without the reputation to cast votes?

Comment: Related: [Add the ability to create any tag synonym to the “trusted user” privileges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79151), [Can we allow 7.5K users to suggest tag synonyms without a score of 5 in the tag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103211)

Comment: Voted to close as a duplicate, but here's another +1 because I *really* think this should be implemented. The current system is completely worthless, no one can earn enough rep on the obscure tags to propose synonyms.

Comment: There was some discussion of these specific tags previously: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112118/how-should-we-disambiguate-the-apn-tag

Comment: Man, I thought I did a decent amount of searching first. There's nothing new under the sun. Ever. :)

Comment: is that why threads are always started on meta for such merge requests?

Comment: @prusswan: Yes, that's one of the reasons. The other reason it makes sense to post Meta questions about retag requests is when there needs to be some discussion about the best way to retag all of those questions. Better to come to a consensus *first* before taking any action.

Comment: I agree, and I've voted for all of the previous feature requests along these lines. It's extremely frustrating to be the top user in some of the tags associated with one like this, yet unable to even vote on a synonym because I have only 2 or 3 upvotes in this particular tag.