# Synonym request: [apns] -> [apple-push-notifications]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

I noticed that we have both a [apns](/questions/tagged/apns) tag and an [apple-push-notifications](/questions/tagged/apple-push-notifications) tag. Can these be synonymized?

[apns](/questions/tagged/apns) (1,079) excerpt:

> Apple Push Notification Service (APNS for short) is the centerpiece of iOS's push notifications feature. It is Apple's service for propagating information to devices (such as iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch devices) and computers (such as Macintosh computers running OS X 10.7 or later).

[apple-push-notifications](/questions/tagged/apple-push-notifications) (1,408) excerpt:

> The Apple Push Notification Service is a service created by Apple Inc. that was launched together with iOS 3.0.APNS is used together with Mac OS X Lion Server to push update notifications to clients that have registered to receive updates via a configuration profile and are also using the server's ...

They are obviously the same thing - could we synonymize [apns](/questions/tagged/apns) => [apple-push-notifications](/questions/tagged/apple-push-notifications)?

Comment: Yes, I think so :)

Comment: Thank you, @AndrewBarber!  See also [previous](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120562/135887) [discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112118/135887).

Comment: I asked for it [several months ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184502/synonyms-requests-of-android-gcm-and-apple-push-notifications). I'm glad it's finally granted.